# How to pay my customers with Django PayPal Payment Pro

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I want to pay my customers with Paypal Payment Pro , I mean send some money from my Merchant account to a Personnal account . At the momment i just can ask the client to give his credit card infromations ane send the money to my Merchant account but I want the reverse.

PS : I use Django WPP https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal

Comment: "I want to pay my customers". Er, business: you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to do a refund?

Answer (score 1):

Use Mass Payments. I was looking at [this site](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1181/) to figure out how to use it with django. It worked like a charm. Your customers need to have paypal accounts though, but I don't think that's an issue if you're paying them.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the PayPal Payment Pro API works. It allows you to accept money, not to send money. You want to use [Mass Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay) or the [Adaptive Payments API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments).